# AAD method AcquireTokenAsync giving System.NullReferenceException error

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, dynamics-365

I have registered my Dynamics 365 app in the Azure active directory and now I'm trying to create an authentication token which I want to use with my web API call.

The issue I'm facing is that authContext.AcquireTokenAsync method is failing with the following exception:

> System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
>   Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
AuthenticationParameters ap = AuthenticationParameters
    .CreateFromResourceUrlAsync(new Uri(apiUrl)).Result;

string resourceUrl = ap.Resource;
string authorityUrl = ap.Authority;

authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUrl, false);

//User Credentials from the AppConfig
UserCredential credentials =
    new UserPasswordCredential("myusername", "password");

//Generate the AuthToken by using Credentials object.
authToken = await authContext
    .AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUrl, applicationId, credentials);
```

Please note that `authContext` is not `null` and none of the parameters are `null`.

Comment: Can you show the type of `applicationId` and [which overload of `AcquireTokenAsync` you are calling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.authenticationcontext?view=azure-dotnet#methods)?

Comment: applicationid is a GUID like 08be0504-303f-4385-cab4-8420d8ff29zg. The overload of AcquireTokenAsync method I'm using is AcquireTokenAsync(string clientid, string resource, UserCredential usercredential)

Comment: what is the full stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: please post your full stack trace - it shows file and line numbers. and in your code, try to refer which line it is where exception occurs.

Comment: The issue was that the authentication token returned by the AcquireTokenAsync method was null. authToken is a class level boject and I was tyring to access its property authToken.AccessToken in a subsequent method. The debugger was throwing exception at the line authToken = await authContext
    .AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUrl, applicationId, credentials) but it was caused by the subsequent method where I was accessing its AccsessToken property.